# Troubleshooting C# SQL insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Up until a few hours ago, this code and similar code worked fine. I dropped and recreated the database to change the timestamp datatype so it would show as the time the record was updated. That is fine now, I've used `current_timestamp` to fix it.

That was the ONLY change I made to the database, otherwise it's the same server, same database name, same connection string in VS2017. I even changed servers a few days ago and nothing went wrong but for some reason this code hasn't worked since I dropped it.

Can anyone suggest why? Was the code just originally flawed?

```
protected void BtnSubmitPost_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string bpTitle = txtBlogHeader.Text;
        string bpBody = txtBlogBody.Text;

        using (SqlConnection addBlogConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["childrens"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand addBlogCmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                try
                {
                    addBlogCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    addBlogCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO blogPosts (bp_header, bp_body) VALUES (@bpTitle, @bpBody)";

                    addBlogCmd.Parameters.Add("@bpTitle", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = bpTitle;
                    addBlogCmd.Parameters.Add("@bpBody", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = bpBody;
                    addBlogCmd.Connection = addBlogConn;

                    addBlogConn.Open();
                    lblBhError.Visible = false;
                    //lblStaffConfirm.Visible = true;
                    lvBlogs.DataBind();
                    addBlogConn.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                    Response.Redirect("/staff.aspx");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the error you are encountering, what line it manifests and the data that you are passing in, please?

Comment: If you dropped and re-added the database, did you remember to re-adjust the permissions?  It's possible your database user is orphaned from your login.

Comment: It's not an error exactly, it's just not inserting data, even though it is reading data from the db. I've inserted breakpoints and it breaks ALLL the way through

Comment: Please remove/comment out the try/catch and see if it throws an exception.

Comment: Also, where are you actually executing the sql?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Rahul below pointed that out, however, adding that line makes enters the data in duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't see you are executing the command `addBlogCmd` at all since there is nothing after `addBlogConn.Open();` statement. Moreover, neither I see you are using disconnected architecture by means of dataadapter/dataset. So probably that explains the problem.

Essentially you are missing `addBlogCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` statement to execute the command you have prepared

Comment: I'll add that back and see if it works but I took it away because when the code was working it was causing a duplicate entry to the db

Comment: re-adding addBlogCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

works but it is still adding duplicate entries

Comment: Thanks so much Rahul, I know that was a rookie mistake but I'm glad you took the time, I also fixed why it was giving me duplicates.